# Slowing testnet for testing

Tags: transactions, debugging

How can I slow down the blocks produced in a local test environment or pause the processing of transactions and diagnose the state of the blockchain?
I would like to really slow it down, instead of a block produced every halh a second, maybe once every 2 minutes.

I suspect it has to do with the `genesis.json` settings but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **pause** and **resume** block production on your node through the corresponding HTTP API calls. The documentation is here:

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference

To enable the pause/resume calls on your node you have to:

1. Add these two plugins to your `config.ini` file:

   ```
   plugin = eosio::producer_api_plugin
   plugin = eosio::http_plugin
   ```
2. Use these commands to actually pause and resume block production on your node:

   ```
   curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/producer/pause
   curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/producer/resume
   ```

PS: unsure at this time on how to ***slow down*** block production.

Comment: Able to submitted a transaction even when the block production is paused. Is it something odd ?

Comment: Like @AmiHeines said: please start a new question, if you want detailed and serious answers.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried changing this, but the block time is set [**here.**](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/config.hpp#L42)

```
const static int      block_interval_ms = 500;
```